# How to pass variable as argument when executing a shell script from jenkins

Tags: linux, shell, unix, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a pipeline script in Jenkins and executing a shell script like below.

```
steps {
                script {
                    def creds = com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.CredentialsProvider.lookupCredentials(
                    com.cloudbees.plugins.credentials.common.StandardUsernameCredentials.class,
                    Jenkins.instance,
                    null,
                    null
                    );
                    for (c in creds) {
                        if(c.id == '9d64a593-d40d-4ba2-9ec8-6bxxxxxxxxx') {
                            println( ( c.properties.password ? "ID: " + c.id + ", UserName: " + c.username + ", Password: " + c.password : ""))
                            uname = c.username
                            pwd = c.password
                            println("uname - " + uname)
                            sh './runUIContainerLogin.sh "${uname}" "${pwd}" '
                        }
                         
                    }
                }
            }
```

At the last when I am running the shell script runUIContainerLogin.sh the variables are not passed to the script though I have $1 and $2 mentioned in the script for 'uname' and 'pwd' respectively. I am getting null value ("") for uname and pwd in shell script.

Please help me to get the variable values in script which are getting passed at the time of runUIContainerLogin.sh execution.

Comment: Regular groovy string with single quotes `''` doesnt support string interpolation, use double quotes instead: `sh "..."`.

Comment: Great! Changing from single to double quotes solved the issue. Thanks.

Comment: One doubt, I want to replace a character (@) in the variable uname  like this  uname.replace('@','%40')  but replace function not working getting 

hudson.remoting.ProxyException: groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: hudson.util.Secret.replace() is applicable for argument types: (java.lang.String, java.lang.String) values: [@, %40]

Comment: create uname with def

Comment: @SuryaN Checkout [This](https://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/util/Secret.html) - you will need to do something like `uname.getPlainText().replace('@','%40')`

Answer (score 1):

### I would try these steps to help resolve your problem.

1. Test what is passed into the sh commandline
2. If correct call sh with double quotes and remove the single quotes
3. Call the sh commandline with " and reomve the single quotes from varaiables.

---

```
sh "./runUIContainerLogin.sh ${uname} ${pwd}"
```

---

Example:

```
def uname= 'Jenkins'
echo "${uname}"
```

---

Results in:

```
Jenkins
```

Here is some [documentation](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#string-interpolation) including use cases [handling credentials](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/jenkinsfile/#handling-credentials) based on setting the username and password.